# How to iterate into the collection of class objects in node.js

Tags: node.js, es6-class

I have two classes one and two

```
class One {
  constructor(field1, field2) {
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
  }
}
module.exports = one;

class Two {
  constructor(field11, field22, list) {
    this.field11 = field11;
    this.field22 = field22;
    this.list = list;
  }
  add(one) {
    this.list.push(one);
  }
}

module.exports = Two;
```

Third class imports both classes

```
const one= require('./one.js');
const two= require('./two.js');
```

Now, I have a function which creates an object of class two and add some values like,

```
two = new two();
two.add(new one(1,1000)); 
two.add(new one(2,2000));

console.log(two.list);
```

////list is a collection of class one object
Till this point is working fine, I am getting collection

My query is how to iterate through collection
like, I want to access
`two.list[0].field1`
// not getting the property field1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class One {
    constructor(field1, field2) {
        this.field1 = field1; this.field2 = field2;
    }
}

class Two {
    constructor(field11, field22, list = []) {
        this.field11 = field11; this.field22 = field22;
        this.list = list
    }

    add(one) {
        this.list.push(one);
    }
}

two = new Two();
two.add(new One(1, 1000)); 
two.add(new One(2, 2000));

console.log(two.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in code:

- Naming and bracket is not closing correct
- Default list parameter is also written in wrong format

```js
class One {
  constructor(field1, field2) {
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
  }
}

class Two {
  constructor(field11, field22, list = []) {
    this.field11 = field11;
    this.field22 = field22;
    this.list = list;
  }
  add(one) {
    this.list.push(one);
  }
}

two = new Two();
two.add(new One(1,1000)); 
two.add(new One(2,2000));

console.log(two.list[0].field1);
```

Updated your code. Try running it

Comment: My issue is I could now access field1 property using list[i],I am not getting the property when I type '.', intellisense do not show the property list on class one, where as pushing the items into list is working correctly and could see the list, two.list

Comment: There are chances there is some misconfiguration in intellisense. Check with editor documentation